# how to read the .text file in MATLAB, which has the following format

Tags: matlab

I have text file in the single line, I am pasting it in the code section, how can I read it in MATLAB in the table or in cells. Currently, I am doing it with the strsplit function and then saving it in cells and to csv, but it is taking lot of time for a single file, as my original data have thousands of rows.

```
[{"ID":1,"Column_A":"red","Column_B":"apple","Column_C":0},{"ID":2,"Column_A":"orange","Column_B":"orange","Column_C":1},{"ID":2,"Column_A":"green","Column_B":"grapes","Column_C":3},{"ID":3,"Column_A":"purple","Column_B":"onion","Column_C":4}]
```

MY technique:

```
data=importdata('example.txt')
columns = strsplit(data{1,1},"},")
%For concatenation
check=[];
for i=1:159929 %total rows in my original file
check = [check ;strsplit(columns{1,i},{':',','})];
end
```

Comment: "how"-> you write code to read it, mostly. Or are you asking us to do it for you? That would be rude. If not, please show us what you tried, reading a text file in MATLAB is one of the most asked questions for the language.

Comment: I have tried to use the strsplit to split the data but it is taking alot of time, as my data is bigger, so I am asking if I can try any other method which can be fast.

Comment: Unless you show your attempt and why its not what you want *with code*, its unlikely you will get help.

Comment: I have attached my attempt,

Comment: Thanks! 
It may be way easier to just go with `fopen` `fread` approach, as you can also read lines one by one with that. 
I also think that one of the causes of your slowness is that `check` keeps incrasing per iteration, as MATLAB is telling you with the warning you see in your editor.

Comment: The problem is text file is stored in one line as I mentioned , do you suggest any technique that can be used to read this in a line wise?

Comment: Okay, changed the code, and working a bit faster now.
for i=1:159929 %total rows in my original file
check{1,i} = strsplit(columns{1,i},{':',','});
end